# Is PHP usort really so slow or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array (Well, a PHP array... which is not really an array. But you get the point.) of objects representing SMSs. One of the fields in these objects is of type DateTime, and I want to sort the array by that field. *I can not sort the data in DB, I'm receiving it from a web service that I can not change*, so please don't suggest that. I sort the array with the following snippet of code:

```
usort($smsMessages, function ($a, $b) { 
    if ($a->SendTime == $b->SendTime) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a->SendTime < $b->SendTime) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This works, but it takes **160 seconds** to sort 30.000 elements.

Now, I know that php is slow, but this is ridiculous. Is there something wrong with the way I wrote this? Is `usort` known to be slow/broken/buggy? Should I use another method? Roll my own?

Comment: Seriously, you complain about sorting 30K elements?

Comment: Does the 160 seconds include the time connecting to the web service ?

Comment: Can you not do an `ORDER BY` (or something similar) when you get the data?

Comment: On i7 (4th gen) it takes (your code) ~1.3 secs for 30k elements.

Comment: @u_mulder - I'm complaining about 160 seconds of time it takes to sort lousey 30k elements.

Comment: @u_mulder: It shouldn't take three minutes.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PZZDNFqN

Comment: @frz3993 - no, getting data from service takes less than 1 second. I measured time specifically for this block, admittedly, with `microtime` calls, but since the server is otherwise unoccupied this really isn't an issue. The sorting block is problem.

Comment: @JeremyJackson - yeah, I could **sort it**.

Comment: @Davor but does my below suggestion have a proportional effect on your code and lowers the overall time measurably ?

Comment: @JeremyJackson: Read the question!

Comment: I would suggest to prevent working with 30k objects; not just because of memory, but also because very often (always) it's a slow way to process big amount of data. In the worst case (when you can't make it in the DB) use arrays of scalars. If you had 1mil SmsMessages would you create 1mil php objects too?

Comment: Also do you really need DataTime objects as well? It's often cool to have, but for 30k records I'd use float / int, otherwise you will have a number of conversions, what of course, takes time.

Comment: @Axalix - no, I recieve data as JSON, and I could use it as strings, int timestamps, whatever. Do you think it would be significant for performance? It's literally just sorted by date, paginated, and then shown to the end user.

Comment: It will be way faster 100%. Can you show the JSON? One question, when you measure time, you exclude `retrieving data from a remote service` time - correct?

Comment: @Axalix - yes, I start measuring after I have received JSON and parsed it, converting into DateTime. The funny part is that that process takes less than 2 seconds. var_dump of parsed JSON is a big array of objects like this: `[0]=> object(stdClass)#347 (5) { 
        ["sender"]=> string(11) "From: 123456789" 
        ["recipient"]=> string(16) "To: 123456789" 
        ["text"]=> string(18) "sms message text" 
        ["id"]=> string(10) "1416243158" 
        ["sent"]=> string(23) "14-11-17 16:52:38" } 
        `

Comment: oh, but that means that you measure time of `json_decode` as well. This is one of the slowest function, especially when you work with 30k elements.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. We needed to sort 2-10 million arrays. Each array contained about 30 fields (strings, integers and NULLs). The first field was a unique integer that we used for sorting.

We used PHP 7.1

It took 4710 seconds (= 78.5 minutes) to sort 2,028,830 items on AWS EC2 r4.large.

Our code looked like:

```
usort($this->rows, function ($item1, $item2) {
        return $item1[0] <=> $item2[0];
});
```

Then I figured out that replacing `$this->rows` with `$rows` makes it almost 4 times faster:

```
usort($rows, function ($item1, $item2) {
        return $item1[0] <=> $item2[0];
});
```

It decreased execution time from 4710 to 1195 seconds.

Another approach is to use [Min Heap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splminheap.php) for `$this->rows` instead of plain PHP array `[]`. It leads to about the same performance improvement. In this case you don't need usort at all.

**Bottom line:** 
 1. but yes, it does take surprisingly huge amount of time even after changes above.
 2. usort is way quicker than MinHeap for already sorted arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You could try speeding up the above code to see if the sorting is in fact the bottle neck, you could try speeding it up by using a global function with it and shortening the code ( Disclaimer: massive microoptimization, could be this is not where your issue is at!) like so:

```
function sort_function($a, $b){
 $a = $a->SendTime;
 $b = $b->SendTime;
 if ($a == $b) return 0;
 return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($smsMessages,'sort_function');
```

Assuming most SendTimes are not equal this should in fact speed things up.

**But** please understand that the above is a very slight speedup only. If you actually see things got to like 140s => you can blame usort here. In all likelihood though, the above suggestion's value for you lies in learning that the usort part of things is not your issue in my opinion.

**Added after more input below:**

After likely having learnt that this is all about a lack of memory (the numbers for usage you posted are about the system overall, I cannot deduce how much of those 256MB are actually in use without more knowledge of these objects :) ), how does this code compare in runtime for you ?

```
$dates = array();
foreach ($smsMessages as $key => $obj) {
    $dates[$key] = $obj->SendTime;
}

asort($dates);
$dates = array_keys($dates);
$sorted = array();
foreach ($dates as $key) {
    $sorted[] = &$smsMessages[$key];
}
```

This should need significantly less memory since it doesn't use an implicit foreach loop on the huge array but just on the array keys.

Comment: And your code takes ~0.5 sec. on i7 (4th gen), 30k elements.

Comment: At least I apparently know how to micro optimize :D Let's see what happens to those 160s :P

Comment: @Axalix add more properties to your object, definitely OP doesn't sort just objects with single property.

Comment: Yes, it went down to 152s :) @u_mulder - yes, the objects have additional fields of sms_text, sender and recipient. None of those are used in sorting, and they should have no influence on sorting speed. The memory usage on 30k elements is also negligible.

Comment: Umm wow that is fairly crazy 8s difference was the least expected outcome to be honest ...

What if you just run this code :

$arr = array();
foreach($smsMessages as $msg) {
  $arr[] = $msg->Sendtime;
}

How long does this take ?

Comment: @ArminBraun - 0.16s. No idea what is wrong here. I'll probably roll some sort of custom sort function later to see what happens after that. I'm starting to think that my PHP is bugged.

Comment: This would in fact suggest a lack of RAM though. I will add code than would run faster in this case above in like 20 min, brb so to say

Comment: @ArminBraun - I got these stats from /proc/meminfo: 'MemTotal: 8075928 kB', 'MemFree: 3026172 kB', 'MemAvailable: 6652156 kB', and memory_limit 256M from phpinfo().

Comment: Those numbers don't mean much I fear. I'd need the memory actually used by PHP. But check out the above suggestion that should take a lot less memory imo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First, add "true" to the `json_decode` as a second parameter, so you will get an associative array instead of array of objects.
(I would also recommend to try this to speed up JSON: https://github.com/RustJason/php-rapidjson - it requires PHP7 though)

And then:

```
$sentTime = [];
foreach ($smsMessages as $key => $element) {
    $sentTime[$key] = strtotime($element['sent']);
}
array_multisort($sentTime, SORT_DESC, $smsMessages);
```

*(0.19 secs on my comp.)*

You can convert some `$smsMessages` into objects later at the moment when you really need them with `(object)$smsMessage` or using your own/customized method.

Comment: I was sorting arrays of log entries (ranging from 20 to 150000 entries) by timestamp and this approach (first extract sort key from each entry, then use array_multisort) is *much* faster than usort()! Thanks for this!